# How to call luis dialog from general dialog and luis dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using node js, I want to call luis dialog("morningUpdate") from 
general dialog("work")

```
dialog.matches('morningUpdate',[    
    function (session, args, next) {
  }
]);

bot.dialog('/work', [
  function (session, args) {
    //how to call here "morningUpdate" dialog
  }
]);
```

how we can achieve this.

Comment: morningUpdate is the name of your dialog or the name of an intent in LUIS?

Comment: name of intent is morningUpdate. It mean name of intent and dialog both are same

Comment: So you want to call the LUIS dialog manually, instead of just using the LUIS recognizer?

Comment: yes i want to call LUIS dialog manually sometime ,and some time it will call by LUIS recognizer

Comment: Ok, I added the question... the standard beginDialog should do the trick.. have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is actual answer

[link for code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2741#issuecomment-307430385)

```
dialog.matches('morningUpdate', 'morningUpdate');
   bot.dialog('morningUpdate', [    
        function (session, args, next) {

        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To call a new dialog, you can just use `session.beginDialog('nameOfDialog');`. Take a look at the [basic](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-basicMultiDialog) and [advanced](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-MultiDialogs) Multi Dialogs samples.

If you need a LUIS sample, take a look at this [one](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS).

Comment: Your dialog definition in the code is wrong, I assume you changed your dialog to be 

bot.dialog('morningUpdate', [...]); 

dialog.matches does not define a dialog.

Comment: dialog.matches  is correct and it works for me.. You can check to https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1929

Comment: your solution session.beginDialog('nameOfDialog'); is giving error Error: Dialog[*:morningUpdate] not found.

Comment: So you don't have a dialog with that name.. The error is clear I think. Take a look to the samples I linked. Also in the same repo you will find a sample using LUIS too.

Comment: i have dialog called morningUpdate, and it is calling from luis recognizer without any problem.

Comment: matches is usually used as part of trigger actions, basically, you define dialogs that are triggered when the Luis recognizer detects an intent that matches it https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS/app.js#L80. Post your full code if you want specific help for your sample. I'm sharing you samples that show how to do things in the standard way. You can still use the intent dialog and the matches function though

Comment: In fact, the second link that you share talks about calling LUIS not calling a LUIS dialog; there is a difference; one thing is to call a dialog, another thing is to call LUIS directly.

Comment: From second link i was trying to show you,dialog.matches are using by other people to. and it's work. I am using bot builder from last 4 month. matches is used for call dialog from luis recognizer.I am not using trigger.

Comment: See if https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS helps you; if not.. please update your question with the specific request, with the code to repro the issue, etc.

Comment: Any way Your solution work for me. I changed it, But still not clear about matches

Comment: did you checked link https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1929 Developer only suggested for matches. it's confusing